# Losing $scope variable using Parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

Today I started studying Angular using Parse, and I'm having an issue. When I create a Query to have all data of a table from Parse all goes good, but when I create a **$scope.variable** for send that array to the view, it's not having anything. I think I'm losing the variable.

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.controller('listadoFiestas',function($scope, $state) { 


      var lista;
      Parse.initialize("xxx", "xxx");
      var Fiestas = Parse.Object.extend("Fiestas");
      var fiesta = new Parse.Query(Fiestas);

      fiesta.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for(var i=0; i<results.length;i++) {
              lista = (
                  {
                  'nombre': results[i].attributes.nombre,
                  'descripcion': results[i].attributes.descripcion
                  }
                );
            }
            $scope.lista = lista;
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("error");
        }
      });

      $scope.variable = lista;



});
```

Maybe someone can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

`$scope.variable = $scope.lista`

to have everything from the `lista` variable also in the `$scope.variable`.

You should be able to access `$scope.lista` already in the view, because it is bound to your scope, so you don't need to save it to a separate variable on the scope.

**Update:**

You should push results to the variable `lista` which should also be initialised like this:

```
var lista = [];
```

and then do:

```
lista.push({ 'nombre': results[i].attributes.nombre,
             'descripcion': results[i].attributes.descripcion});
```

Comment: if I put only $scope.lista doesn't prints anything.. That's my view.            <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="listadoFiestas">
               {{lista}}
  </body>

Comment: See my updated comment and please also try to assure, that you have some data in `results` => just do a `console.log(results)` inside the success callback to confirm.

Comment: Yes I also had this error.. thank you, but now I only see [] in the view. If I do console.log(list) inside success has the data, but when I make it out of success, in the last line, it only has [].

Comment: the success function is asynchronous which means you do not have the data right away outside and you need to bind it to a variable on `$scope` inside the success function. If you use the variable on scope later, it will be automatically filling the view with data when the asynch action is finished. You must have an error somewhere else.